# jQuery doesn't recognize function when it's added later

Tags: jquery

Below is a snippet of my JS

It loads JS functions if PHP asks for them. But for my question this isn't really important.

Almost at the bottom of my example you'll find: `loadjscssfile("js/functions/"+data.action+".js", "js");`
What it does is this: let's say `data.action = 'helloworld'` it will load the file: js/functions/helloworld.js AND it will check for the function `helloworld()`
The problem is in the last part, the helloworld.js gets loaded. But when I do a: `$.isFunction('helloworld')` it doesn't work.

**UPDATE:
The jQuery function AJAX does the trick, below also the solution**

```
//
// LOAD JS OR CSS
//
var fileref;
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
     if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
      fileref=document.createElement('script');
      fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
      fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
     }
     else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
      fileref=document.createElement("link");
      fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
      fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
      fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
     }
     if (typeof fileref!="undefined"){
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
     }
}
//
// SET INIT AJAX FUNCTION
//
function init(i){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "ajax.php?i="+i
    }).done(function( data ) {
        if(data.menu!='N.U.'){
            $('.menu').html(data.menu);
        }
        if(data.container!='N.U.'){
            $('.container').html(data.container);
        }
        if(data.action!='N.U.'){
            if(data.action_val!='N.U.'){
                var funcCall = data.action + "('" + data.action_var + "');";
            } else {
                var funcCall = data.action + "();";
            }
            if($.isFunction(funcCall)){
                eval(funcCall); 
            } else {
                //
                // function doesnt excist try to load function from dir
                //
                loadjscssfile("js/functions/"+data.action+".js", "js");
                //
                // try again
                //
                if($.isFunction(funcCall)){
                    eval(funcCall); 
                } else {
                    //alert('FATAL ERROR: JS function ('+data.action+') doesnt excist');
                }
            }
        }
    }).fail(function(){
        alert( "error" );   
    });
}
```

**SOLUTION**:

```
//
// SET INIT AJAX FUNCTION
//
function init(i){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "ajax.php?i="+i
    }).done(function( data ) {
        if(data.menu!='N.U.'){
            $('.menu').html(data.menu);
        }
        if(data.container!='N.U.'){
            $('.container').html(data.container);
        }
        if(data.action!='N.U.'){
            if(data.action_val!='N.U.'){
                var funcCall = data.action + "('" + data.action_var + "');";
            } else {
                var funcCall = data.action + "();";
            }

            if (typeof window[data.action] === "function") {
                eval(funcCall);
            } else {
                //
                // function doesnt excist try to load function from dir
                //
                $.ajax({
                  url: "js/functions/"+data.action+".js",
                  dataType: "script"
                }).done(function(){
                    //
                    // try again
                    //
                    if (typeof window[data.action] === "function") {
                        eval(funcCall); 
                    } else {
                        alert('FATAL ERROR: JS function ('+data.action+') doesnt excist');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).fail(function(){
        alert( "error" );   
    });
}
```

Comment: And you are certain your file is being loaded? If you add a `Console.log` message in the file, does it get written to the console?

Comment: you should use the onload handler of new added script to use it as callback once script loaded. Then your method will be available

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more; I don't understand it really (thanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `<script>` tag like that, the script is loaded asynchronously, usually *after* your Javascript code returns to the main event loop. So the functions defined by the script won't be available immediately after `loadjscssfile` is loaded.

You should use jQuery's `$.getScript()` function. It takes a callback function, which will be invoked once the script has been loaded.

Also, your check `$.isFunction(funcCall)` is not correct. `funcCall` is a string, like `"helloWorld()"`, and a string is not a function. If you want to know if the function is loaded, you would have to do `$.isFunction(window[data.action])`. `data.action` is the name of the function, and `window[data.action]` gets the value of the global variable with that name.